# Multivariable matrix calculus textbook?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, matrix-calculus

I study a multivariable calculus course, and the lecturer is using matrix calculus notation, which I'm not familiar with. The notes that come with the course aren't sufficient in understanding this notation. Are there any good calculus textbooks you could recommend, which use and introduce matrix calculus notation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A couple of oldies that I think fit what you're asking are: Williamson/Crowell/Trotter's [**Calculus of Vector Functions**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/013112367X) and Embry/Schell/Thomas's [**Calculus and Linear Algebra: An Integrated Approach**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0721633706). Both books write matrices out fully, even at the expense of wasting a lot of space on the pages, and both books are at what I'd roughly call the low end of (U.S.) honors level (2nd year undergraduate) multivariable caclulus. [Apostol's **Calculus**, Volume 2 would be at the mid to upper end honors level.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a textbook, but [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-vectors-and-matrices/) unit from MIT might help. The unit is part of MIT's 18.02 course, which is their multivariate calculus course, with the first unit (the one linked) being about vectors and matrices. The units after that talk about calculus with matrices, and should introduce any notation you are having trouble with. Simply look through the course and see if the topic you are covering in lecture is there and then either read the accompanying notes or watch the lecture, and the notation should be introduced.

Answer (score 0):

[This MIT short course on matrix calculus](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-s096-matrix-calculus-for-machine-learning-and-beyond-january-iap-2023/) may be helpful.